# Unity Editor Pipeline Scripting: how to Pass Sprite to SpriteRenderer in OnPostprocessSprites() Event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

after importing sprites inside unity , i want to make a Prefab out Of them and assign them a SpriteRenderer and BoxCollider2D component , all automaticly.
every thing is good exept i cant pass the imported Sprite to the SpriteRenderer component any how.
i dont knoow what im missing here. any help will be appritiated.

```
void OnPostprocessSprites(Texture2D texture, Sprite[] sprites)
   {

    Sprite sp = sprites[0];
        TextureImporter importer = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        importer.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;

        GameObject GO = new GameObject();
        GO.name = sp.name;
        string ResAddress = importer.assetPath.Remove(importer.assetPath.Length - 4, 4).Replace("Assets/Resources/", "");
    Debug.Log("Resource Address = " + ResAddress);//  Images/Objects/car      acceptable for Resource.load

        //GO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sp;// not works
        GO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = (Sprite)Resources.Load(ResAddress);// not works

        GO.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        Object prefab = PrefabUtility.CreateEmptyPrefab(string.Format("Assets/Resources/X_Temp/{0}.prefab", GO.name));
       if (prefab != null)PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(GO, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);

    }
```

there is no Error or messages , it makes the prefab with BoxCollider And SpriteRendere Components But SpriteRenderer's Sprite Field Has No Sprite, and set to none or Missing.

how can i fix this? 
also asked in Unity Community And No luck.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1434068/how-to-pass-sprite-to-spriterenderer-in-onpostproc.html

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-pass-sprite-to-spriterenderer-in-onpostprocesssprites-event.505638/

====== UPDATE And NOT RECOMMENDED ANSWER ======

```
void OnPostprocessSprites(Texture2D texture, Sprite[] sprites)
{
    TextureImporter importer = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
    if (AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(importer.assetPath)==null)
    {
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        return;
    }

    foreach (Sprite sp in sprites)
    {
        importer.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;

        GameObject GO = new GameObject();
        GO.name = sp.name;

        Sprite sprite = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(importer.assetPath);
        GO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;

        string address = string.Format("Assets/Resources/Prefabs/{0}.prefab", GO.name);

        PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(address, GO);
        PrefabUtility.ReconnectToLastPrefab(GO);
    }
}
```

not recommended Because Of the following Crash Error :

```
 A default asset was created for 'Assets/Resources/Images/Objects/car.png' because the asset importer crashed on it last time.You can select the asset and use the 'Assets -> Reimport' menu command to try importing it again, or you can replace the asset and it will auto import again.UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh()
```

Comment: @Programmer  yes its definitely returns null , because the Importer.assetPath not returning the Acceptable Address for Resource.load() . the thing is , even hardcoding the acceptable path for Resource.Load() not works.
it seems that, against what the Unity Doc Says, the importer work is not completely Finish when Triggers the OnPostprocessSprites() Event.
i will Update the Code.thanks

Comment: do you import your assets to Resources folder?, just to make sure

Comment: @Programmer of course before saying "definitely" i tested what you sayed .  

1- where can i find Image Import Settings,i don't know what you mean?!


2-folder where i import sprites :Assets\Resources\Images\Objects    - 
Unity Version : unity 2017.1.1f1  -  Image File Name: car.png

Comment: @endrikexe . yes i import assets to Resourses folder .

Answer (score 1):

This is really interesting. I don't think that `Resources.Load(ResAddress)` is returning `null` otherwise you should see `null` if you use `Debug.Log` on it. I assumed that the `texture` variable from the `OnPostprocessSprites` function would work if you convert it to `Sprite` then assign it to the `SpriteRenderer` like so:

```
Sprite tempSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
GO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = tempSprite;
```

That didn't work too despite the fact that `tempSprite` is **not** `null`. This quickly made me remember the [`AssetDatabase`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html) API which is *specifically used to access and operate on assets*.

You are looking for the [`AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html) function. It will return the **proper** `Sprite` asset you can use to change the `SpriteRenderer.sprite` property.

This should work:

```
Sprite sprite = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(assetPath);
GO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = tempSprite;
```

It would make sense to call `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` after all these but it seems to work without calling `AssetDatabase.Refresh()`. I still think you should call it.

Comment: thanks, it does the job. but there is one problem . the     `AssetDatabase.Refress() ` Causes some kind Of Crash ,and makes the `OnPostprocessSprites` event runs Again. the result is 2 prefab One without the Sprite And Other With the Sprite.  All the code Runs twice . the error is:  
**" A default asset was created for 'Assets/Resources/Images/Objects/car.png' because the asset importer crashed on it last time."**  as i mentioned first, it seems the actual file Is not Placed In Project When  Unity Triggers ` OnPostprocessSprites` Event.

Comment: If `AssetDatabase.Refress()` is causing some crash then don't use it. It seems to work without it.

Comment: not working without `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` . Updated the Question With Not Recommended Answer Script. any suggestion on preventing the crash message?!

Comment: Please do not change your original code and complain that it doesn't work. Take your **original** code in your question and simply change `GO.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = (Sprite)Resources.Load(ResAddress);` with the 2 lines of code from my ansswer. That's it. It should and it works %100. I am not sure what you are doing in the second code you just posted.

Comment: did you test it your self?! cant get it to work any how without `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` .i think its unity bug. about the secound code, as i said in comments, Importer **Does NOT** include the Sprite Files In Unity when we Attempt to Reach it in `OnPostprocessSprites()` via `Resources.Load` Or `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()` . And its obvios that `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` causes a Crash.so With a Controlled Crash everything can be Handeled.and Of cource you know the `foreach` Loop is for suppurting the Multiple Sprite Input. Was It so bad?!Really Appritiate your Helps And your Follow Up.